# conformal deformation with fixed boundaries

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, computational-geometry, conformal-geometry, quasiconformal

For a flat plane with certain boundary, e.g., a rectangular patch, is it possible to conformally displace or deform such patch to a curved bump with exact same boundary? In this [thesis](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~keenan/Projects/ConformalGeometryProcessing/thesis.pdf), Dr. Keenan proposed the so-called spin transformation which seems a solution to realize conformal displacement. My question is, for a given bump from a planar surface, can we find an explicit conformal mapping between its projection to the flat plane and itself?

Comment: Can you use precise terminology instead of "flat place", "patch", "bump"?

Comment: A flat plane or patch here means a bounded area on a planar surface, e.g., the region subjected to x^2+y^2 <=1 on z=0 plane in 3D space. And a bump with the same boundary is certain surface such as z=1+cos(pi*(x^2+y^2 )).

Comment: Every two simply connected hyperbolic surfaces can be conformally mapped onto each other, so what is your question again?

Comment: My question is how to get the exact expression of an conformal mapping, analytically or numerically, for the given two surfaces ( such as the two surfaces above), not just only an abstract notion.